# Unable to see Debug SQL Queries in Spring boot 3. How can I see SQL queries with logging.level.root as warn

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

This is the application.properties file I am using currently.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student_tracker
spring.datasource.username=springstudent
spring.datasource.password=springstudent
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

# Turn off the spring boot banner
spring.main.banner-mode=off

# Reduce logging level. Set logging level to warn
logging.level.root=warn
# Add logging configs to display SQL statements
logging.level.org.hibernate.sql=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind=trace
```

I am unable to see logs wen `logging.level.root` is set to `warn`. However, setting it to `debug` works but all debug logs are cluttered.

How can I see only hibernate logs while keeping `logging.level.root=warn`?

Comment: Do you have a logging configuration file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for `JPA`:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

The first line logs the SQL queries, and the second statement logs the prepared statement parameters.

And this should work for `JdbcTemplate`:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils=TRACE
```

Similar to the `JPA` logging configuration, the first line is for logging statements and the second is to log parameters of prepared statements.